# Is there a way to change the browser clock with Playwright Python?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I need to change the clock of the Playwright Python browser. I know this can be done [in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960549/can-i-set-the-date-for-playwright-browser), but is there a way to do this with the Python Playwright library? I've tried converting the JavaScript code to Python but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `evaluate`-method to execute Javascript on the page:

```py
import playwright

def execute_js(page):
  page.evaluate(
    """
    page.evaluate(() => {
      Date.now = () => {
        return 1609477200000; //Jan 1, 2021
      };
    });
    """
  )

with playwright.create_browser().new_page() as page:
  execute_js(page)
  print(page.evaluate("Date.now()"))
```